# Java GetBound Gives Original Polygon Position not Current

Tags: java, collision-detection, polygons

I am using the GetBounds method as part of collision detection for a game and it is doing some rather strange things. GetBounds returns a bounding box for the original position of my polygon, but not the current position that i have moved it to. This is very confusing as when i draw my polygon it appears in the correct place. I feel it is likely that i am making a mistake with moving my polygon so i have included a detailed description of how i am moving it.

The way i am changing the polygons position is by modifying the array "xpoints" and "ypoints" which are inherited from the class polygon. The xpoints and ypoints arrays are modified by adding the desired location of the polygon to a different array containing the polygon at location 0,0 and replacing the array.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Sword extends Polygon{

int[] SwordXPoints, SwordYPoints

public void main(int DesiredLocation){
for(int i = 0; i < super.ypoints.length; i++){
super.ypoints[i] = SwordXPoints + DesiredLocation;
}
for(int i = 0; i < super.xpoints.length; i++){
super.xpoints[i] = SwordYPoints + DesiredLocation;
}
}
}
```

I hope this explanation is easier to understand and simpler.

Thanks, Sam.

Comment: this is not even complete and you are using your own classes swords etc so how the hec do we knoe what you are doing in there??

Comment: Sorry gpasch, this seemed to make sense to me. I'll rewrite it and try to refrain from using any specific code sampled from my game and just rewrite it to be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `getBounds()` runs this bit of code:

```
if (bounds == null) {
    calculateBounds(xpoints, ypoints, npoints);
}
return bounds.getBounds();
```

The first time through, `bounds` is null and `calculateBounds` is called. This walks through your points, calculates min and max X and Y, and creates `bounds`. On subsequent calls `bounds` is not null and the cached value is returned.

What you need to do is add a call to [invalidate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#invalidate()) after you have finished updating all of the points.

Alternatively, you can use `AffineTransform` to alter the origin and scale of the `Graphics2D`, draw your polygon as is, and restore the original origin and scale. The rough sequence of calls would be:

```
AffineTransform origAT = g2.getTransform(); // Save original
AffineTransform newAT = new AffineTransform();
newAT.concatenate(origAT);
newAt.translate(newX, newY);
g2.setTransform(newAt);
g2.draw(polygon);
g2.setTransform(origAt); // restore original
```

Comment: Thanks Devon_C_Miller. This is a perfect explanantion of why it isn't working. I would like to know where you actually found that code,I spent quite a while browsing oracle's site and could not find any code of how get bounds works.

Comment: @SamChapman When you install the JDK, somewhere in the installation is a `src.zip` which contains the Java sources. In a pinch, you can unpack that and have a look. However an IDE should let you control click on a symbol and see the source. I haven't tried Eclipse, but I know it work in both NetBeans and IntelliJ IDEA.